# Windows 7 - translucent drag manager?

Tags: windows-7, drag-and-drop

When dragging a file from Windows Explorer into other apps, I now get a nice icon of the files I drag. I cannot remember this from previous Windows versions so I was hoping that they finally implemented the equivalent of the Translucent Drag Manager where you can associate a transparent image with the drag contents. Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really new to Vista and/or Win7.
You can create such a drag image with the [IDragSourceHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762034%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface. Or you can create your own manually without that interface.

All you have to do for this to work is to implement the IDataObject::SetData and IDataObject::GetData methods so that they allow custom formats.